# Issue in external JQuery with Angular 7

Tags: jquery, angular

I have some external JQuery files comes along with Bootstrap template. Actually JQuery is for SideBar menu to open/close the menu. I've created separate component for it.

Issue:
When I put this extenal JQuery file into index.html or angular.json file, it is not working and even click event not getting trigger.

Index.html

```
<body id="page-top">
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="./assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./assets/js/stylish-portfolio.js"></script>
</body>
```

Angular.json

```
 "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/assets/css/bootstrap.css",
              "src/assets/css/stylish-portfolio.css",
              "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/js/jquery.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/jquery.easing.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/stylish-portfolio.js"
            ]
```

But, When I add this JQuery into Component's typescript file, it starts working.
Typescript File:

```
 declare var $: any;
 ngOnInit() {
    $(".menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
      $(".menu-toggle > .fa-bars, .menu-toggle > .fa-times").toggleClass("fa-bars fa-times");
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
  }
```

As far as I know, whatever JQuery file we keep into Angular.json or Index.html file, it should work. what is wrong here..

Comment: I'd suggest you rewrite this jquery code in an "Angular Way". There is not much here

Comment: issue is, I can write whole JQuery file into Angular way, I have shown piece of code here, but actually it is 2000 lines of JQuery file given with Bootstrap Template

Comment: alright, then check answer. Should help